# Looking for material regarding forging alliances

Tags: system-agnostic, roleplaying

As a player, I'm the head of a persecuted resistance group, and I need to make friends and allies in order to secure resources.

I don't know where to start though, I have many doubts I don't even know how to formulate and I believe a good read would help a lot.

I'm aware this is primarily opinion based so I'll make it more concrete : is anyone aware of any chapter in any rpg related book that would reference this ?

Comment: This might be less broad if you specify a genre or system family, such as fantasy, or d20-based. Advice from Edge of the Empire probably won't help at all in a Pathfinder game due to differences in both theme and mechanics.

Comment: Is this something that is the core of the campaign or something you do on the side as "your own thing"? 
Is this something you want resolved with the group or as part of downtime?

Comment: @Derek Stucki funny you should mention EotE because I'm playing a Star Wars game set in Legacy, and we players are Roan Fel's imperial knights. I do believe general advice given could help any system, as negociations techniques are not really system dependant, are they ?

Comment: @JP Chapleau it is a central part of the campaign. Not the central part but when you're persecuted wherever you go, securing allies and resources becomes quite important indeed. In that regard it's not really a group thing even though everyone tries to bring something to the table ; and sometimes it becomes a group brainstorming when we're under pressure and we have no alternative.

Comment: I'm afraid that you may not find information general enough from an RPG book. Would this be better answered on worldbuilding.se?

Comment: I agree with @DerekStucki, I don't think this is the right/best site for this. This is more than a simple RPG question... You need to define your wants/needs/goals/what you have to offer/trade/deal. If you are stuck, work with your GM to get a few leads. Complete sandboxing leads to choice paralysis. Ask him for a few ideas or points of contact to start and go from there..